# Define newcommand inside a loop

Tags: foreach

In my latex document I have defined an array of element and I am making a loop within this array.
I would like to define newcommand inside this loop.
The idea is to make

```
\newcommand{\name1}{
  \begin{center}
     \scshape{name1}
   \end{center}
}


\newcommand{\name2}{
  \begin{center}
     \scshape{name2}
   \end{center}
}


\newcommand{\name3}{
  \begin{center}
     \scshape{name3}
   \end{center}
}
```

What I did is:

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\def \peopleArray {name1, name2, name3}
\foreach \x in \peopleArray {
  \newcommand{\x}{
     \begin{center}
        \scshape{name3}
      \end{center}
  }
}
```

but this won't work.

I have also tried this

```
\foreach \x in \peopleArray {%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname \x\endcsname{\begin{center}
            \scshape{x}
    \end{center}}
}
```

but this doesn't work either

Comment: It would be nice if you could give a simple compilable example... notice however that  numbers can't be part of a LaTeX macro name (although you can do tricks, see for example package `etoolbox`, maybe `\csuse` and company can help you), and then, `\scshape` is a switch, so you should use `{\scshape wwhatever}`.

Comment: In addition to what @Rmano says, each cycle in a `\foreach`  loop is executed in a group, so the `\newcommand` will be lost.

Comment: @Rmano well, the code won't have any number in it. I just used them for the sake of the example.
What I don't understand in your comment is: so it is not possible?

Comment: @FabienneLablatte Perhaps it's better that you make a more “real world” example, then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to define a sequence of macros with a for loop, with an example of usage:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\def \peopleArray {\nameA, \nameB, \nameC}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in \peopleArray {
  \expandafter\newcommand\x{}% error if already defined
  \expandafter\gdef\x{
     \begin{center}
        {\scshape name3}
      \end{center}
  }
}
\nameA
\nameB
\nameC
\end{document}
```

I had to use `\gdef` instead of `\newcommand` because otherwise the definition is local (and lost) instead of global.

I'm not sure this is useful though, because `name3` is the same in all cases.

Comment: you should add \newcommand so that you get a error if you overwrite an existing command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How would you make the `\newcommand` global?

Comment: you don't have to, you can use \newcommand to test and then \gdef